# How can I get Calendar Button's value using its key inside the while loop, PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, calendar, pysimplegui

I am very new to PySimpleGUI. I am building a GUI for a desktop application and wanted to use a calendar. But there came a problem with retrieving the value of Calendar Button events in the while loop without timeouts in **window.read()** when I chose from Calendar Picker Popup. I tried to get its value using **event == 'CalendarButton's text'**, but couldn't, though its button text changes every time if you choose to set a different date. Can you please help with that, or how can I get its (or any element's) value using its key inside the while loop. Or at least can I use Tkinter calendar package. If so, how can I connect Tkinter Calendar with PySimpleGUI window, will I have to use an element's key bindings with Tkinter?

Here's my code for Calendar Button definition which I put into my window's layout:

```
sg.CalendarButton('Calendar', target='_CALENDAR_', pad=None, font=('MS Sans Serif', 10, 'bold'), 
                button_color=('red', 'white'), key='_CALENDAR_', format=('%d %B, %Y'))
```

> and here's the while loop events handling part

```
# LOOP EVENTS #
while True:

    # READ EVENT VALUES #
    event, values = window.read()

    # EXIT OR CLOSE EVENT #
    if event is None or event == 'Exit':
        break

    # BUTTON EVENTS

    # CALENDAR BUTTON CLICKED EVENT #
    if event == 'Calendar':
        window['_CALENDAR_'](disabled=True)


# CLOSE WINDOW
window.close()

# POPUP
sg.Popup('Title',
        'The results of the window.',
        'The button clicked was "{}"'.format(event),
        'The values are', values)
```

Also, I cannot see this event's value in the sg.Popup() output after I exit the window

'EDITED' Sorry, there were errors in **sg.Popup()**. Now fixed it.

Comment: For the popup, you've got 2 errors.  The "button clicked" is in the "event" not the values variable.  You've got a syntax error on the last line... an extra ' after values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to both save the value and get the event is to create a hidden input field. Enable events for the input field and you'll get an event when the calendar fills in the input field that you set as the target.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [  [sg.Text('Calendar example')],
            [sg.In(key='-CAL-', enable_events=True, visible=False), sg.CalendarButton('Calendar', target='-CAL-', pad=None, font=('MS Sans Serif', 10, 'bold'),
                button_color=('red', 'white'), key='_CALENDAR_', format=('%d %B, %Y'))],
            [sg.Exit()]]

window = sg.Window('Calendar', layout)

while True:             # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event in (None, 'Exit'):
        break
window.close()
```

Comment: Never used the **enable_events** attribute before, that's cool. That solved the problem very much @MikeyB. One more question is it possible to make a drop-down calendar button, maybe with **sg.InputCombo()**. If yes, then, I would very much appreciate any suggestions on that. Or at least, is it possible to change the layout of the popup calendar window (ways to edit _background color_, _font_, and etc.).

Comment: These kinds of detailed questions are best answered on the GitHub.  Open an Issue.